# Flask API working in postman and browser but throwing errors in JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, flask

My Flask API is working on Postman and also works when i call it on browser, like (http://127.0.0.1:5000/)  but when i call this API in JavaScript code (by Fetching HTTP or any other method) it throws errors on console [Here is the error scene on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GL5Jc.png)
FLask Code is given below:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify,request
from flask_restful import Api, Resource


app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Home(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return jsonify("Hello Word!!")

api.add_resource(Home,'/')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", debug=True)
```

[Here is the output of this code on browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcJai.png)

When i call the Api in Code(My Web Project), it throws error.

JavaScript Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>The XMLHttpRequest Object</h2>

<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Request data</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
<script type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script>
function loadDoc() {
    fetch('https://127.0.0.1:5000/hospitalData')
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((myJson) => {
    console.log(myJson);
  });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks for the suggesting correction, please help me out

Comment: Is the AJAX call being made from *exactly* the same domain as you're calling? ie. `https://127.0.0.1:5000`?

Comment: yes same laptop, same IP address localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you enable CORS? did use `http://127.0.0.1` instead `https://127.0.0.1`